# ProGuard will make Spring Bean name conflict

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proguard

Startup error

```
2020-11-06 18:07:31.452  WARN 13120 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.maple.MapleApplication]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'a' for bean class [com.maple.a.d.a.a] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.maple.a.b.a]
2020-11-06 18:07:31.463 ERROR 13120 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.maple.MapleApplication]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'a' for bean class [com.maple.a.d.a.a] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.maple.a.b.a]
```

I tried to use Spring `definition.getBeanClassName()` naming rules, but it didn’t work. Is it too much trouble if you want to manually set the name of each bean on the annotation? Can ProGuard provide the function of not repeating the class name? I haven’t found it yet.